# How do I check my app's version-number on Google Playstore when coding in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I want to know if there is a method or library to use in checking my app's version-number on Google PlayStore?  Want to advise users to update to the latest version if their apk's version number is behind

Comment: Use native platform code or dependency and then call it from flutter side on every  launch.

Comment: please which native code or dependency are you referring to?

Comment: Like any native dependency which checks the latest version of app. like this one -> https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater

Comment: this will work perfectly for native android. But I need one for flutter @Harshapulikollu

Comment: You can use plaform channels https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels and call that  code from initState() of your homepage. Use a Dialog option to show user.

Comment: Check this tutorial blog https://medium.com/@naumanahmed19/prompt-update-app-dialog-in-flutter-application-4fe7a18f47f2

Answer (score 6):

There is no official API at the moment. And using the solutions you find on the web are bad. Most of them involve scraping the Play Store website and will break whenever the Play store re-designs their web page.

Right now I would recommend using [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). That way you can store in the Firebase server whatever you want the minimum version for your app to be, and them when you want users to update you can increase the value. This lets you control when you need to force an update and is much more flexible, and very easy to update.